# EF Core 3.1 Cosmos DB provider: Find out RUs (Request Units) consumed

Tags: azure, ef-core-3.1

a quick question - Can EF Core 3.1 Cosmos DB provider tells how much RUs (Request Units) consumed by each operation (query or command)? (Similar to what .NET Cosmos SDK provides)

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a description what the abbreviation "RU" stands for.

Comment: @Sud Did you find an answer to this?

Comment: Sorry, unable to find the answer so far